# can't get checked nodes from RadTreeView in code behind

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radtreeview

I have a rad tree view as below:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="rtreevwParvandehShakhsi" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" TriStateCheckBoxes="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableViewState="true"></telerik:RadTreeView>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:PigisConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT SCT_ParvandehShakhsi.*, ParvandehShakhsi_ID AS Expr1, ParvandehShakhsi_Code AS Expr2, ParvandehShakhsi_Desc AS Expr3, ParvandehShakhsi_ParentID AS Expr4, ParvandehShakhsi_Personel_ID AS Expr5 FROM SCT_ParvandehShakhsi WHERE (ParvandehShakhsi_Personel_ID = @personel_ID)">
     <SelectParameters>
     <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="user_personel_id" Name="personel_ID"></asp:SessionParameter>
      </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitParvandehShakhsi" runat="server" Text="ثبت" OnClick="btnSubmitParvandehShakhsi_Click" CausesValidation="false" Font-Size="Medium" CssClass="btn green" Height="38px" Width="63px" />
```

and I want to get the checked nodes in code behind. i use below code but it dont get the checked node for me! where is the problem?

```
 protected void btnSubmitParvandehShakhsi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RadTreeNode tnode in rtreevwParvandehShakhsi.CheckedNodes)
    {
        RadWindowManager1.RadAlert("node value : " + tnode.Value, 330, 180, "پیام سیستم", null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: does rtreevwParvandehShakhsi.CheckedNodes property not contain any tree node??

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the DataSourceId of the treeview manually on Page_Load if it is not PostBack.

I think the treeview's datasource gets overriden on page load before the the button click event fires leading to CheckedNodes being empty.